# Hadoop fully distributed mode

Tags: hadoop, cloud, mapreduce, hdfs

I am a newbie to Hadoop. I have managed to develop a simple Map/Reduce application that works fine in 'pseudo distributed mode'.I want to test that in 'fully distributed mode'. I have few questions regarding that;

1. How many machines(nodes) do I need (minimum & recommended) for processing a file size of 1-10GB?
2. what are the hardware requirements(mainly, I want to know the # of cores, Memory space and disk space)?

Comment: You will have to provide more information about the type of processing, API you are using, input file type etc. for anyone to give you an educated guess of what a decent cluster would look like. Given that, for nodes of same spec, your performance will scale linearly hence it would be easy to benchmark this on your own and figure out the answer by adding 1-2 nodes and recording the timing of your hadoop job.

Answer (score 2):

I'd check out Cloudera's hardware recommendations: http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2010/03/clouderas-support-team-shares-some-basic-hardware-recommendations/

A snippet from that page

Various hardware configurations for different workloads, including our original “base” recommendation:

- **Light Processing Configuration
  (1U/machine):** Two quad core CPUs, 8GB
  memory, and 4 disk drives (1TB or
  2TB). Note that CPU-intensive work
  such as natural language processing
  involves loading large models into
  RAM before processing data and should
  be configured with 2GB RAM/core
  instead of 1GB RAM/core.
- **Balanced Compute Configuration (1U/machine):** Two quad core CPUs, 16 to 24GB memory, and 4 disk drives (1TB or 2TB) directly attached using the motherboard controller. These are often available as twins with two motherboards and 8 drives in a single 2U cabinet.
- **Storage Heavy Configuration (2U/machine):** Two quad core CPUs, 16 to 24GB memory, and 12 disk drives (1TB or 2TB). The power consumption for this type of machine starts around ~200W in idle state and can go as high as ~350W when active.
- **Compute Intensive Configuration (2U/machine):** Two quad core CPUs, 48-72GB memory, and 8 disk drives (1TB or 2TB). These are often used when a combination of large in-memory models and heavy reference data caching is required.